# Strongly typed common parameters of Functions Array

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have a function with given logic:

```
function superFunc(funcs: Array<(...args: any[]) => any>): (...args: any[]) => void {
    return function (...args) {
        funcs.forEach((func) => {
            func(...args);
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any way for me to type it in a strong way to suffice the following cases:

```
const func = superFunc([
    (a: string, b: number) => {},
    (a: string, b: number) => {},
]); // (arg_0: string, args_1: number) => void

const func1 = superFunc([
    (a: string, b: boolean, c: string) => {},
    (a: string) => {},
]); // (arg_0: string, args_1: boolean, args_2: string) => void

const func2 = superFunc([
    (a: string, ...args: number[]) => {},
    (a: string, b: number) => {},
]); // (arg_0: string, ...args: number[]) => void

const func2 = superFunc([
    (a: number, c: string) => {},
    (a: string, b: number) => {},
]); // never
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work - using the property of typescript that if functions have compatible call signatures they're expanded into an array type of the function. Therefore we can try and extract the array value, and if it's a union, then evaluate to never:

```js
type IsUnion<T, B = T> = T extends B ? [B] extends [T] ? false : true : never;
type ExtractArrayValue<A extends any[]> = A extends (infer V)[] ? V : never;

type SuperFunc<F extends ((...args: any) => any)[]> =
    IsUnion<ExtractArrayValue<F>> extends true
        ? never
        : ExtractArrayValue<F>;

function superFunc<F extends ((...args: any) => any)[]>(funcs: F): SuperFunc<F> {
    return function (...args) {
        funcs.forEach((func) => {
            func(...args);
        });
    } as SuperFunc<F>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICSBnAqgOwJYHt0B4AVAGngCF4BeeAgPkuvlgA9xZ0ATZM%20AfngG1SAXUYs2nAQRF8AZgEMANsgQAueOABOAV1Xx0sAG6wNAbggwEAURYa5AY3ABBDbcgA1RTryPRrDlzl0SH4hOiofZj8JAApMdBljeDcAShDeJPg1fSNTUHM4eABlLTgNADEtdDs8Mt9xLmjogDoWuQ0Ac2Q1QMhkyjoe1NDKUHgxpDQsXDxrTXsnFzl3T1gamjpI%20vVtWFHx-b5s4z39sbVZ2wdnVw8FLzKaMzAQGUqHHHR4ZBLjCqqaur%20eCNFpNNqdbpBPoUAZQkI0aKvKpdeBlZJqYqlP7VB7wADeJ3gGlg4C0Gk%20SPeuGBoPByD6BJAp3GlOQTRk2A0lnsAAtGpToXRGczmZTmq0OvSniL4ABfZLS8ay%20ByLiY35vNZPWV5EB2XDIcDwSn0b5Yt7RfiE6JyNSGjRxdokABGWS0AFtncZBfjZURrbavppHS63Z7vf1ff6QEIFfAAPTx4HggD6AAY7cH0E6VZKUwBGMNejQ%20gzYTDsXX69CG41vfOmn7lC1WpnjG2Zh3Z0PwZ3YbAKWCBEh2TuOn14v0BsfZidTmNxxPJjrpmc5ukFtR9gdD9AkDcAJjXpfLlee1drlIPjfNVUt06DXZztMlReMITn0f2HcfId7b5LSNJ2jWMTATJMbRXDNf27eAXwhPQPWLD9IzLCsqwNI1KQAZhvDU71bb9A3QJDjBHY8gPnIi1x7Ejw0AmEo1AUDwL0QxjCAA)

Comment: Shame it doesn't work with tuples. By I could figure something out with this answer, thanks!